# Code Academy JavaScript Arrays - I can't see why this code is incorrect (newbie)

Tags: javascript

I cannot figure out what I did wrong here.

```
var names=["isaac","nathan","eva","seth","max"];
for (var i=0; i<names.length;i++){
console.log("I know someone called "+ names[i];)  
}
```

Comment: Well, a good place to start would be with the indication that anything *is* wrong.  What would that indication be?  When trying to solve a problem, it's usually best to first identify the problem.

Comment: `names[i];)`.. remove `;`

Answer (score 0):

semicolon is on wrong place bro!!!

```
console.log("I know someone called "+ names[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in line 3. names[i]; you shouldn't have the semicolon here you should get it after ). ;) Don't worry about making errors while learning.